# Passing parameters to onClick handler using Butterknife

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I want to handle onClick event for specific view, and pass some parameters to handler.

Right now I have created a function and passing `View` and my params to that function and implementing onClick handler in that function as follows.

```
private void doSomething(View view, String... params)
{
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //  params is available here
        }
    });
}
```

**My question is does butterknife allow to pass additional parameters to handler? if yes how? (docs does not explain)**

Comment: Nope `Butterknife` does't  allow this

Comment: @Nilesh Is it a common use case?

Comment: which case you are talking about?

Comment: @Nilesh passing params to handler.

Comment: Nope why you wan to pass parameter in function and then set onClicklistener

Comment: @Nilesh imagine I have a list of views and each view have some value associated with it and on click of each view I want to pass that value to handler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100963/discussion-between-kishor-pawar-and-nilesh).

Comment: Refer to this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/427

Comment: @muazh : That was me only. I opened that issue. and the solution Jake gave, worked really well.